# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing when using function split in Python

Tags: python

I have learned c and c++, and I am trying to learn python these days...but I have ran into a problem I just can't understand...

```
a,b = input().split()
print(a)
print(b)
```

if I execute this short code, "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" this is the error message I get...I have looked for the questions with the same error message, but it didn't solve my problem...

in order to understand the problem, I've tried various things, and I figured something which I find kinda weird...

```
a = input()
print(a)
```

if I execute this code, it works well when I input a integer value, but when I input a string, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" this kind of error message appears...

am I doing sth wrong? or is there sth that I don't know that makes this code look flawless to me when this is indeed wrong?

Comment: Both codes are working all right for me. What python version are you using and what is your system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
$ cat a.py
a,b = input().split()
print(a)
print(b)
```

Let's run it first under python3:

```
$ python3 a.py 
1 2
1
2
```

(`1 2` is what I typed at the prompt.)

Here is the same code running under python2:

```
$ python2 a.py 
1 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    a,b = input().split()
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

This shows the same error that you report.

**The issue is that `input` means something different in python3 than it did in python2.**  Under python3, `input` simply reads in as a string what the user types.  Under python2, `input` both reads user input *and* evaluates it.

To make the code work the same under python2 as it did under python3, we need to replace `input` with `raw_input`:

```
$ cat b.py
a,b = raw_input().split()
print(a)
print(b)
```

And, observe:

```
$ python2 b.py
1 2
1
2
```

If you have a choice, you should be using python3.  Python2 is approaching end-of-life.